# Not able to manipulate mysql using python

Tags: python, mysql-python

> ImportError:
>   dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so,
>   2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.1.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-38-darwin.so
>   Reason: image not found

I am experiencing this type of errors for SQL related libraries in python.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `openssl` installed? How did you install `MySQL`?
If you have `homebrew` you can try to install `openssl` with it, it should provide that `.so` file:

```
brew update && brew upgrade
brew install openssl
```

Comment: yes i have openssl and already tried brew update && brew upgrade
brew install openssl

Comment: does it matter how i installed mysql

Comment: I am not sure.
You could also try to:
$ sudo pip install pyopenssl
see if that helps?